# Reading Binary File to Linked List

Tags: c, list, binary

I have been trying for to write and read between a binary file and a linked list. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Save:

```
currentContact = firstContact;


while( currentContact != NULL )
{
fwrite (currentContact->firstName, sizeof currentContact->firstName, 1, myFile);
fwrite (currentContact->surname, sizeof currentContact->surname, 1, myFile);
fwrite (&currentContact->age, sizeof (int), 1, myFile);
fwrite (currentContact->telephone, sizeof currentContact->telephone, 1, myFile);
currentContact = currentContact->next;
}
```

Load:

```
  fread( &numContacts, sizeof( int ), 1, myFile );            
  newContact = realloc( newContact, sizeof( struct Contact ) * 1 );
  countFile = 1;
  while (fread(newContact, sizeof( struct Contact ), 1, myFile))
  {
     fread(newContact->firstName, sizeof newContact->firstName, 1, myFile);
     fread(newContact->surname, sizeof newContact->surname, 1, myFile);
     fread((&newContact->age), sizeof (int), 1, myFile);
     fread(newContact->telephone, sizeof newContact->telephone, 1, myFile);

     if (countFile == 1)
     {
        firstContact = newContact;
        newContact = NULL;
     }
     else
     {
        currentContact = firstContact;
        count = 0;
        while( count != countFile )
        {
           if( strcmp( newContact->surname, currentContact->surname ) < 0 )
           {
              newContact->next = currentContact->next;
              currentContact->next = newContact;
           }
           currentContact = currentContact->next;
        }

     newContact = NULL;
     }

     countFile++;               
  }
  fclose( myFile );
```

EDIT:

After applying some changes, there is still an error on the second parse through the loop where it goes to fread the file again...

```
                newContact = realloc( newContact, sizeof( struct Contact ) * numContacts );
            countFile = 1;
            while (countFile != numContacts + 1)
            {
                fread(newContact, sizeof (struct Contact), 1, myFile);

                if (countFile == 1)
                {
                    firstContact = newContact;
                    newContact = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentContact = firstContact;
                    count = 0;
                    while( count != countFile )
                    {
                        if( strcmp( newContact->surname, currentContact->surname ) < 0 )
                        {
                            newContact->next = currentContact->next;
                            currentContact->next = newContact;
                        }
                        currentContact = currentContact->next;
                    }

                newContact = NULL;
                }

                countFile++;                    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one problem is the following statement:

```
while (fread(newContact, sizeof( struct Contact ), 1, myFile))
```

The above statement is attempting to read something into the memory pointed to by `newContact`.  Based on the way the data is written, this *might* not be correct.  And based on the fact that the next statements inside the loop read the individual members, then it is not correct.  So that `fread` inside the while loop should probably be eliminated.

Some other potential issues:

- The code should probably be allocating memory for each new contact (since what appears to be the first allocation is only for a single element).
- The `next` pointer should be initialized to NULL at some point (realloc does not zero out memory).
- The linking in of new elements appears to have some issues.  For example, if the new element is the new first element, then the head pointer `firstContact` should be updated.  Also, if the new element is greater than all existing ones, it will not be added to the list.
- The code should check the result of fread (for error conditions).

**After OP Edits**  The allocation for the entire list in one piece is a reasonable idea.  However, it is necessary to update newContact to point to the correct piece of memory at each iteration in the loop.  You could keep a separate pointer variable for maintaining that information.  In addition, the change to read the entire contact in one piece needs to be reflected in the writing code too.  As is, the amount of data written and read is unlikely to be the same (e.g., the structure has a next member variable that takes up space and is not reflected in the written data.

Comment: I've change it so that it allocates memory for the full contact rather that single elements: fread(newContact, sizeof (struct Contact), 1, myFile);

The file is saved in order anyway, so each new entry should be the last entry in the list, so the last issue shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The last issue is still a problem - step through it in the debugger.  The new item will not be added to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've managed to work it out now. There were multiple silly mistakes that I managed to work through with your help and with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is already at

```
fwrite (currentContact->firstName
```

what you need to do is write the whole structure not writing each member

`fwrite (currentContact, sizeof(type of currentContact),..` // or whatever your struct is called.